# Why are some web clients requesting a page named "cache"?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, debian-squeeze

We see errors like this in the apache error log:

```
[Thu May 17 14:32:35 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] File does not exist:
/home/www-data/mywebsite.com/r/cache, referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/r/1010
```

It is strange because:

1. There is no reference in the code/url about a folder/file "cache".
2. The folder/file "cache" does not exist
3. The client is randomly trying to access a "cache" folder everywhere on the website.
4. It is always trying to access the folder/file "cache" following this pattern:

Pattern:

```
/level1/.../levelwhatever/filename (referer)
/level1/.../levelwhatever/cache
```

We run a LAMP (Debian stable: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze9. We also use APC 3.1.3p1). We use Google Analytics and AdSense.

We do not know how to reproduce the problem.

Note: I replaced the user's IP in the code for privacy.

Comment: That client is on an internal IP address - do you have access to the client system?

Comment: I replaced the public ip by a private one for privacy issue. No issue there. :)

Comment: I mean, can you touch a client system making this request in order to troubleshoot?

Comment: Not sure I understand. http://www.mywebsite.com/r/1010 is valide. there is no reason in the code for the browser to open http://www.mywebsite.com/r/cache which would return a 404.

Comment: Right - which tells me that the browser (or, bot - whatever this HTTP client is) is misbehaving.

Comment: We suspected a bad script/bot. Nope, it happens to "real" users.

Comment: Is there an entry in the access log for a request to the `cache` directory?

Comment: There is not only one specific url which is being accessed. The client is randomly trying to access a "cache" folder in the same url as the referer page.

Comment: Ok - but please check the access log anyway.  This will confirm that the client is indeed the problem, and not a misbehaving module on the server, for instance.  Then, can you confirm whether or not you have access to a client system that is making these requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Chrome browser had a bug (Issue 132059:)
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059

for specific versions (19.0.1084.52-2 19.0.1084.56 not with 18.xx)

Comment: Please provide a summary of the bug, as links have a dreadful habit of dying.

Comment: One possible reason is that it's not a Chrome bug, but some malware plugin called "Browser Companion Helper" that makes such requests.

Comment: I added reply on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987688/unknown-http-requests-of-type-http-domain-cache-32-digit-alphanumeric-key/12996119#12996119 (the bug still exists)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be caused by a CMS which offers caching functionality which does not work correctly. The script might want to deliver a cached page to the client, thus the error, even though the client did not directly request this page at all.

You should check the documentation of the CMS you are using for a description of caching mechanisms. It could be a simple configuration error, e.g. the directory permissions are not set correctly so the apache/php process cannot create the cache folder/cannot write to it

Comment: We produced all the code (no CMS). Nowhere in the code a reference to a file/folder cache is done. It looks more like a module/configuration issue (APC, htaccess rewrite, deflate, etc.).

Comment: Ok that is strange then. Does the client have some type of AV/Firewall installed/uses a proxy or uses browser extensions/toolbars? These can perform a sort of URL prefetching/caching which might cause this. To be sure it is not one of these temporarily disable all security products, use a direct (non proxy) connection to the webserver and use a browser without toolbars/extensions